# Raycast from one point to other rotating point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to create a laser beam effect in a game.

Basically I'm using line rendered for that. I have to draw line from player to certain point, that point rotates in the screen. Now I have to get a ray cast at that point to create 3rd reflecting vertex in line rendered.

Physics2d.raycast does not return the exact hitting point. Can you please help me on how can I use ray cast on rotating object. I would be very thankful. I have tried to calculate the angle but there is still difference.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class RayDeflection : TouchHandler
{

        Vector3 p1, p2, orgPos;
        LineRenderer lineRenderer;

        protected const int HITS = 2;
        float RAY_LENGTH = 1.5f;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
                PlayerScript = PlayerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("PlayerScript").gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControlScript> ();

                lineRenderer = transform.GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
                Laser ();
        }
        protected override void OnTouchStart (Vector3 tapPosition, TouchHandler.ScreenTouchType touchType)
        {



        }

        protected override void OnTouchMoved (Vector3 tapPosition, Vector3 deltaMove, float duration, TouchHandler.ScreenTouchType touchType)
        {
                //RaycastCheck ();  
                Laser ();
                //Laser (tapPosition);
        }


        protected override void OnTouchEnd (Vector3 tapPosition, float duration, TouchHandler.ScreenTouchType touchType)
        {

        }



        // Update is called once per frame
        void Laser ()
        {

                //p1 = transform.position;
                orgPos = transform.position;        

                p1 = transform.right * RAY_LENGTH;


                {
                        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (orgPos, p1);

                        lineRenderer.SetPosition (0, transform.position);


                        //Debug.DrawRay (p1, p2);

                        //  
                        if (hit.collider != null) {         
                                //  Debug.LogError (hit.collider.name);

                                p1 = hit.point;
                                lineRenderer.SetPosition (1, p1);


                                Vector3 distVect = (transform.position - p1);
                                Vector2 shotVect = new Vector2 (distVect.x, distVect.y);    

                                Vector3 rVect = Vector3.Reflect ((p1 - orgPos), Vector3.right);
                                Debug.LogError (p1);

                                p2 = rVect * RAY_LENGTH;



                                //  Debug.DrawRay (p1, p2);

                                if (hit.collider.tag.Equals (Constant.tag.items)) {

                                        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount (3);
                                        //                      
                                        lineRenderer.SetPosition (2, p2);
                                } else {
                                        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount (2);
                                }
                        } else {
                                lineRenderer.SetVertexCount (2);
                        }


                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to be more specific about you have tried and share some of that code if anyone is going to help you.

Comment: [As far as I can tell, `Physics2d.Raycast` _does_ return the hitting point.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-point.html)